# React Hook testing with renderHook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library

I want to test the state update of the component using renderHook from @testing-library/react-hooks, which let us render the hook in the same way as we do in a react functional component.
Just want to know, is this only applicable for custom hooks, because the state is not getting changed when I am trying this for testing a component

```
it('test count update', () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useState({ count: 0 }));
    const [state, setState] = result.current;
    const wrapper = mount(<ComponentToTest />);

    act(() => {
       wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
    })
    expect(state).toBe({ count: 1 });
})
```

getting an error since the count is not getting updated and still remains 0

Can anyone please help

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[From the docs](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/reference/api#renderhook):

> Renders a test component that will call the provided callback, including any hooks it calls, every time it renders.

`renderHook` is used to test the hook itself, not a component that uses that hook. `renderHook` itself *renders a test component*; you cannot test a hook's result by rendering a component that happens to use that hook.

In your case, you're just testing `useState`, which you can absolutely do with `renderHook`:

```js
it('test count update', () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useState({ count: 0 }));
    const [state, setState] = result.current;
    setState({count: state + 1});
    expect(state).toBe({ count: 1 });
})
```

But that seems kind of pointless; we know `useState` works.

If you want to test a component that uses `useState` (or any hook), you need to render the component itself and assert the result of that hook in the rendered component. E.g.

```js
it('test count update', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<ComponentToTest />);

    act(() => {
       wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
    })
    // assuming the result is rendered in a span with a classname of 'result'
    expect(wrapper.find('span.result').text()).toBe('1');
})
```

Comment: bro, you have logic in your first test. Not good.  You should be testing it as a black box, but instead you're testing the test

Comment: Indeed, that is the point I was illustrating! Testing the test does seem a bit pointless. The second code snippet is more aligned with the approach I take when testing React hooks.